# Collection size in mybatis query

Tags: mybatis

I have a MyBatis query that looks like this:

```
<if test="userIdList != null and userIdList > 0">
            AND galleries.id IN (
                SELECT gallery_id
                    FROM gallery_users
                    WHERE gallery_id IN (
                        <foreach collection="userIdList" item="item" separator="," open="(" close=")">
                            #{item}
                        </foreach>
                    )
                    GROUP BY gallery_id HAVING COUNT(gallery_id) = ???                 
            )
        </if>
```

That part I'm stuck on is getting the collection size which will be dynamic. So how can I get the collection size so that I can properly fill in the '???' value?

Comment: You mean like `${userIdList.size}` ?

Comment: @ave That looks like it might be it. If you like put that as the answer and I will accept once I get a chance to accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can invoke the `Collection#size()` method using OGNL expression. i.e.

```sql
GROUP BY gallery_id HAVING COUNT(gallery_id) = ${userIdList.size}
```

Note that `#{userIdList.size}` won't work here because the expression in `#{}` is parsed by MyBatis' internal expression parser and not by OGNL.